# Why I get TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '') in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I have custom service `service.center.ts` which contains the following delete method:

```
deleteCenter(id: number): Observable<{}> {
  console.log(id);
  const url = `${this.D_ROOT_URL}${id}`;
  return this.http.delete(url);
}
```

I have the button in the template:

`<button type="submit" (click)="deleteCenter()">Delete</button>`

which calls the following method in `list-centers.component.ts`:

```
deleteCenter(): void {
  if (this.getCheckedCenters.length > 0) {
    this.getCheckedCenters.forEach(function (id) {
      id = +id;
      this.centers = this.centers.filter(c => c.id !== id);
      this.centerService.deleteCenter(id).subscribe();
    });
  }
}
```

The `this.getCheckedCenters` returns the array of ids, and I printed with `console.log` which returns valid number.

But the method in `list-centers.component.ts` print error in console, and doesn't call another method in the `center.service.ts`.

Error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.centers')

`centers: Center[];`

Data for centers array:
[image]

Comment: I would guess buy using foreach(function.. you are losing the this scope. Try changing that for a lamda: foreach(p => {...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using foreach(function..., you are losing the this scope. You can try using a lambda foreach(p => {...

This is because of the way typescrypt guarantees scopes in lambdas but not function. You could alternatively use function and a closure